# Jquery table th class contains

Tags: jquery, html-table, contains

I am trying to hide table columns where table header contain certain string.
I also have class name for each column in table header, so as part of best practice, I am planning to update code to find th class name contains certain string. But the second scenario below fails when I am trying to get class name of th. Could some one help me in this part.

Working scenario with `th` contains:

```
var table = $('#tblProjects');
var findColumn = $(table.find('th:contains(' + columnName + ')'));
```

Not working scenario with class of `th` contains:

```
var table = $('#tblProjects');
var findColumn = $(table.find('th.attr('+'class'+'):contains(' + columnName + ')'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do this, which I mention because you say you are trying to use best practices, would be to give all of the columns you want to hide a specific class like 'hideMe'. Remember, html elements can have multiple classes so this would just be an extra one on top of everything else. After that you could do:

```
var findColumns = $('#tblProjects th.hideMe');
```

Notice the selector there, '#tblProjects th.hideMe'. I am saying find all th elements with a class 'hideMe' that are inside of #tblProjects.

Understanding css selectors and how they work is critical in jQuery, have a look a this reference: [css selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)